# Whitespace before dot (method call) allowed in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I want to use the following syntax in Javascript:

```
var bar = foo.replace(/really long regex/, something)
             .replace(/another really long regex/, something)
             .replace(/yet another really long regex/, something);
```

since it's (somewhat) more readable than doing this on one line.

Is this allowed?  It works fine in Firefox, but I can't find any reference to this syntax anywhere, and I don't want to find out later that there's some obsure browser where this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Javascript ignores whitespace.

Although if you are going to ignore whitespace you need to be sure and use semicolons to end your expressions.  Semicolons are not required, but if they are not used, javascript uses carriage returns to separate commands.  Which can cause inconsistent behavior if you're not expecting it.

I have done it many times in my javascript code, since when I'm writing pretty code I don't like to let it go beyond 80 characters.

Take a look at the emcascript standard https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ecma-international.org%2Fpublications%2Ffiles%2FECMA-ST%2FECMA-262.pdf

Line Terminators (which is what your concerned with) are addressed on page 25 of the pdf(page 15 is printed on the sheet).  All of section 7 is about formatting, you'll probably find a definition of why it works there(yep I'm lazy and don't want to read the whole section :) ).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that what I thought, although I was indeed afraid that semicolon insertion might ruin this.  I'll wait a bit longer for a more authoritative answer, but otherwise I'll approve this answer.

Comment: @mscha It's actually recommended that you put semicolons in whenever you end an expression.  This allows you to later use a code minimizer without having the javascript interpreter get confused.  Your code is easier to read(for debugging purposes), but minimized code runs faster, since it takes the javascript interpreter less time to read it.

Comment: @ehudokai: absolutely, I always use semicolons. The question here is: won't some obscure Javascript parser insert a semicolon in the *middle* of my expression?

Comment: @mscha I don't think so.  At least it never has for me.  I'm guessing it looks at the next line to see if it is a continuation of the previous statement.  And since . cannot start a javascript statement, it must assume that it's part of the previous expression.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm convinced.

Comment: Thanks,  I added a link to the emcascript spec in my answer to hopefully give you a definite rule for the standard.

Comment: And thanks for the spec link.  Even the spec is unclear: “In general, line terminators may occur between any two tokens, but there are a few places where they are forbidden by the syntactic
grammar”, but it doesn't say what those places are.  The section on semicolon insertion (page 36/26) helps, though; it explicitly lists all places where you shouldn't have a line terminator, and this is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this but I would be careful. To quote the wikipedia entry - "whitespace in JavaScript source can directly impact semantics". See [JavaScript Syntax -Whitespace and Semicolons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I had seen that, but it doesn't say whether my example is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is I was not able to find any documentation but it is valid.
In your case you could loop over the regexps instead